# Python - Plotting a 3 dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I've not yet worked with a 3 dimensional array and I'm a little confused on how to approach this plotting with its relative large size.

There is relative code to this, but it's not necessarily needed in this case.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

mask1 = (8e+11 < Mvir1) & (Mvir1 < 2.4e+12)
MWmasses1 = Mvir1[mask1]
MWpos1 = Pos1[mask1]
```

MWpos1 will have a shape of `(1220, 3)`

and it looks like this,

```
[[  51618.7265625   106197.7578125    69647.6484375 ]
 [  33864.1953125    11757.29882812   11849.90332031]
 [  12750.09863281   58954.91015625   38067.0859375 ]
 ..., 
 [  99002.6640625    96021.0546875    18798.44726562]
 [  27180.83984375   74350.421875     78075.78125   ]
 [  19297.88476562   82161.140625      1204.53503418]]
```

If there is any additional information left out that is needed, I will be more than happy to post it.

I appreciate any help that is given.

Comment: So you have a collection of 1220 points that you want to plot in 3D? If you have problems plotting that with mplot3d, I would suggest mayavi. It'll easily handle that amount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unpack the values and plot

```
x,y,z = zip(*MWpos1)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot(x, y, z, '.')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[Read more at the tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html)